# Is Thread.yield same as non blocking IO in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, io

I know that non-blocking IO do not block on the calling thread but releases it to do other things while awaiting the IO.

I just learned about [`Thread. yield`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#yield()) method which allows a thread to tell the CPU to run other threads...technically yielding control.

These two things, non-blocking IO and `Thread. yield` sounds similar to me, so I was wondering, at the most fundamental level, are non-blocking IO just `Thread. yield` put to use when doing IO?

Comment: @Kayaman Why not make Answer of your Comment?

Comment: @Kayaman that sound like a pretty go answer to me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR: No, `Thread.yield()` can't and shouldn't be used for **anything**.

The mechanism may seem similar, but `yield()` is not related to and cannot be used to implement non-blocking IO. It's also cumbersome, behaviour is platform dependent, and therefore should [not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979796/what-are-the-main-uses-of-yield-and-how-does-it-differ-from-join-and-interr).

While blocking IO works by having a thread "lock itself" on an input stream and wake up when input arrives, non-blocking IO reverses this and there's a central [selector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html) (a native mechanism) that gets notified when input data is available. It can observe thousands of channels at the same time, and spend zero resources on those that don't require any attention. When data is available on a channel, the selector then directs that data to a worker thread to process. It's efficient, but also different and more complicated than blocking IO.

Since `yield()` only tells the CPU that "I have no work to do, feel free to run other threads while I rest", it's still working in the same way as regular IO. You want to avoid threads that don't have anything to do, and yielding is just actively not doing anything, instead of letting the scheduler determine it.

Now you might think you could write something like the following to simulate non-blocking IO

```
List<InputStream> ins ...
while(true) {
    for(InputStream in : ins) {
        if(in.available() > 0) {
            int input = in.read();
            // do something with input
        }
    }
    Thread.yield();
}
```

You might think that the code acts like a selector. Going through the blocking input streams, checking if they have data to read, if so, reading the data and processing it, and maybe yielding the thread after the loop for good measure.

The above code is flawed mainly because of the call to `InputStream.available()`. It can be used to tell when a call will **not** block if it returns a positive number, but it can return `0` and still not block. You might (and very possibly will) end up looping over those streams forever and not read anything because the logic thinks it will block because `available()` returns `0` just because it cannot be **sure** that it won't block. This is the major difference between blocking and non-blocking IO. The only sure way to know if a read will block with BIO, is to call `read()`. And then you might be stuck.

Here's Stephen's good explanation of problems with [available() in socket programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082709/when-is-inputstream-available-useful).